# Google adsense only to subdomain

Tags: google-adsense

I need google adsense in subdomain only. But when submiting for review it only accept main domain. I mean I need `subdomain.example.com` instead `example.com` How to sovle it?

Comment: You can add a subdomain to your apporved domain once you're in AdSense.

Comment: Adsense need approval of primary domain? Right? But I dont need to approve it. Need only subdomain. Please explain

Comment: The subdomain is configurable once your domain is approved. If you own the `subdomain.example.com`, it means you own the `example.com` domain. Once you are approved for the `example.com` domain, you can add your `subdomain` to the list and show ads there too.

Comment: Ok, thanks.....